# Sinatra respond to 'http://sever/func?key1=value1&key2=value'

Tags: ruby, rest, sinatra

How can I make sinatra code respond to below GET method?

```
http://my.server.address/function?key1=value1&key2=value2&key3=value3
```

Thanks for your kindness.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the only thing in the path is '/function', that's the only thing you have to manage. The host will be dealt with by the server, the params by Sinatra (it makes them available through the `params` method) So we can get this running with this little bit of code:

```
require 'sinatra'
get '/function' do
  params.inspect
end
```

And when we run it locally on port 4567, then go to "http://localhost:4567/function?key1=value1&key2=value2&key3=value3", it returns our inspected params as `{"key1"=>"value1", "key2"=>"value2", "key3"=>"value3"}`

As far as the "my.server.address", that depends on how you're hosting your application. If you have no experience here, the easiest way to get something like this working is to use [Heroku](http://www.heroku.com/).